# including plain javascript file in webpack 2 configuration

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I am trying to load a javascript file that relies on jquery.

```
import "jquery";
import "../../lib/layerslider/js/greensock.js";
import "../../lib/layerslider/js/layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery.js";
import "../../lib/layerslider/js/layerslider.transitions.js";
```

once packaged, I get `require` is not defined in the included `greensock.js` part of the generated javascript.

```
// error on this line (require is not defined)
;eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('!18(t,e){"4I 4J";1b i=t.5r=t.5r||t;1c(!i.3A){1b r,s,n,a,o,l=18(t){1b e,r=t.1t("."),s=i;1d(e=0;r.1f>e;e++)s[r[e]]=s=s[r[e]]||{};1a s},h=l("5p.5o"),u=1e-10,f=18(t){1b e,i=[],r=t.1f;1d(e=0;e!==r;i.24(t[e++]));1a i},p=18(){},19=18(){1b t=az.1A.a1,e=t.2h([]);1a 18(i){1a 1g!=i&&(i 2p 42||"4q"==1k i&&!!i.24&&t.2h(i)===e)}}(),c={},d=18(r,s,n,a){15.59=c[r]?c[r].59:[],c[r]=15,15.5C=1g,15.9D=n;1b o=[];15.6Q=18(h){1d(1b u,f,p,19,m=s.1f,g=m;--m>-1;)(u=c[s[m]]||1j d(s[m],[])).5C?(o[m]=u.5C,g--):h&&u.59.24(15);1c(0===g&&n)1d(f=("5p.5o."+r).1t("."),p=f.4K(),19=l(f.1I("."))[p]=15.5C=n.4i(n,o),a&&(i[p]=19,"18"==1k 3H&&3H.6R?3H((t.8U?t.8U+"/":"")+r.1t(".").4K(),[],18(){1a 19}):r===e&&"37"!=1k 2k&&2k.3n&&(2k.3n=19)),m=0;15.59.1f>m;m++)15.59[m].6Q()},15.6Q(!0)},m=t.3J=18(t,e,i,r){1a 1j d(t,e,i,r)},g=h.8z=18(t,e,i){1a e=e||18(){},m(t,[],18(){1a e},i),e};m.70=i;1b v=[0,0,1,1],x=[],y=g("2A.8A",18(t,e,i,r){15.7b=t,15.7C=i||0,15.7A=r||0,15.7a=e?v.4O(e):v},!0),T=y.8Y={},w=y.8y=18(t,e,i,r){1d(1b s,n,a,o,l=e.1t(","),u=l.1f,f=(i||"5G,6U,5A").1t(",");--u>-1;)1d(n=l[u],s=r?g("2A."+n,1g,!0):h.2A[n]||{},a=f.1f;--a>-1;)o=f[a],T[n+"."+o]=T[o+n]=s[o]=t.2C?t:t[o]||1j t};1d(n=y.1A,n.3T=!1,n.2C=18(t){1c(15.7b)1a 15.7a[0]=t,15.7b.4i(1g,15.7a);1b e=15.7C,i=15.7A,r=1===e?1-t:2===e?t:.5>t?2*t:2*(1-t);1a 1===i?r*=r:2===i?r*=r*r:3===i?r*=r*r*r:4===i&&(r*=r*r*r*r),1===e?1-r:2===e?r:.5>t?r/2:1-r/2},r=["9o","7T","bt","aW","aM,aP"],s=r.1f;--s>-1;)n=r[s]+",ba"+s,w(1j y(1g,1g,1,s),n,"6U",!0),w(1j y(1g,1g,2,s),n,"5G"+(0===s?",aH":"")),w(1j y(1g,1g,3,s),n,"5A");T.bz=h.2A.9o.5G,T.an=h.2A.7T.5A;1b b=g("8q.8p",18(t){15.4n={},15.7R=t||15});n=b.1A,n.9V=18(t,e,i,r,s){s=s||0;1b n,l,h=15.4n[t],u=0;1d(1g==h&&(15.4n[t]=h=[]),l=h.1f;--l>-1;)n=h[l],n.c===e&&n.s===i?h.3c(l,1):0===u&&s>n.2w&&(u=l+1);h.3c(u,0,{c:e,s:i,8Z:r,2w:s}),15!==a||o||a.3g()},n.bm=18(t,e){1b i,r=15.4n[t];1c(r)1d(i=r.1f;--i>-1;)1c(r[i].c===e)1a 2y r.3c(i,1)},n.8v=18(t){1b e,i,r,s=15.4n[t];1c(s)1d(e=s.1f,i=15.7R;--e>-1;)r=s[e],r&&(r.8Z?r.c.2h(r.s||i,{2f:t,2J:i}):r.c.2h(r.s||i))};1b P=t.aJ,O=t.aw,S=84.aN||18(){1a(1j 84).bs()},k=S();1d(r=["6a","bq","9U","o"],s=r.1f;--s>-1&&!P;)P=t[r[s]+"bp"],O=t[r[s]+"bk"]||t[r[s]+"a8"];g("6f",18(t,e){1b i,r,s,n,l,h=15,f=S(),19=e!==!1&&P,c=a5,d=33,m="6h",g=18(t){1b e,a,o=S()-k;o>c&&(f+=o-d),k+=o,h.3q=(k-f)/8l,e=h.3q-l,(!i||e>0||t===!0)&&(h.3C++,l+=e+(e>=n?.aF:n-e),a=!0),t!==!0&&(s=r(g)),a&&h.8v(m)};b.2h(h),h.3q=h.3C=0,h.6h=18(){g(!0)},h.7e=18(t,e){c=t||1/u,d=1i.aD(e,c,0)},h.67=18(){1g!=s&&(19&&O?O(s):ao(s),r=p,s=1g,h===a&&(o=!1))},h.3g=18(){1g!==s?h.67():h.3C>10&&(k=S()-c+5),r=0===i?p:19&&P?P:18(t){1a 6j(t,0|8l*(l-h.3q)+1)},h===a&&(o=!0),g(2)},h.6T=18(t){1a 2n.1f?(i=t,n=1/(i||60),l=15.3q+n,2y h.3g()):i},h.8j=18(t){1a 2n.1f?(h.67(),19=t,2y h.6T(i)):19},h.6T(t),6j(18(){19&&5>h.3C&&h.8j(!1)},aI)}),n=h.6f.1A=1j h.8q.8p,n.2V=h.6f;1b A=g("5N.93",18(t,e){1c(15.1w=e=e||{},15.1D=15.2i=t||0,15.2K=1P(e.4F)||0,15.1C=1,15.2l=e.1X===!0,15.1y=e.1y,15.2F=e.4y===!0,V){o||a.3g();1b i=15.1w.7l?j:V;i.1V(15,i.1p),15.1w.2W&&15.2W(!0)}});a=A.78=1j h.6f,n=A.1A,n.2z=n.1K=n.2u=n.1F=!1,n.1E=n.1p=0,n.1B=-1,n.1h=n.3i=n.3O=n.1r=n.26=1g,n.1F=!1;1b C=18(){o&&S()-k>8E&&a.3g(),6j(C,8E)};C(),n.7P=18(t,e){1a 1g!=t&&15.41(t,e),15.4y(!1).2W(!1)},n.7f=18(t,e){1a 1g!=t&&15.41(t,e),15.2W(!0)},n.aa=18(t,e){1a 1g!=t&&15.41(t,e),15.2W(!1)},n.41=18(t,e){1a 15.2R(1P(t),e!==!1)},n.ah=18(t,e){1a 15.4y(!1).2W(!1).2R(t?-15.2K:0,e!==!1,!0)},n.80=18(t,e){1a 1g!=t&&15.41(t||15.27(),e),15.4y(!0).2W(!1)},n.1G=18(){},n.4H=18(){1a 15.1p=15.1E=0,15.2u=15.1K=!1,15.1B=-1,(15.1K||!15.26)&&15.1H(!0),15},n.5c=18(){1b t,e=15.1r,i=15.1l;1a!e||!15.1K&&!15.1F&&e.5c()&&(t=e.4g())>=i&&i+15.27()/15.1C>t},n.1H=18(t,e){1a o||a.3g(),15.1K=!t,15.2l=15.5c(),e!==!0&&(t&&!15.26?15.1r.1V(15,15.1l-15.2K):!t&&15.26&&15.1r.40(15,!0)),!1},n.2s=18(){1a 15.1H(!1,!1)},n.3R=18(t,e){1a 15.2s(t,e),15},n.3m=18(t){1d(1b e=t?15:15.26;e;)e.2z=!0,e=e.26;1a 15},n.5R=18(t){1d(1b e=t.1f,i=t.4O();--e>-1;)"{5v}"===t[e]&&(i[e]=15);1a i},n.4j=18(t){1b e=15.1w;e[t].4i(e[t+"8h"]||e.5s||15,e[t+"8I"]||x)},n.ab=18(t,e,i,r){1c("bw"===(t||"").1u(0,2)){1b s=15.1w;1c(1===2n.1f)1a s[t];1g==e?4d s[t]:(s[t]=e,s[t+"8I"]=19(i)&&-1!==i.1I("").1m("{5v}")?15.5R(i):i,s[t+"8h"]=r),"4B"===t&&(15.3O=e)}1a 15},n.4F=18(t){1a 2n.1f?(15.1r.2r&&15.8M(15.1l+t-15.2K),15.2K=t,15):15.2K},n.2B=18(t){1a 2n.1f?(15.1D=15.2i=t,15.3m(!0),15.1r.2r&&15.1p>0&&15.1p<15.1D&&0!==t&&15.2R(15.1E*(t/15.1D),!0),15):(15.2z=!1,15.1D)},n.27=18(t){1a 15.2z=!1,2n.1f?15.2B(t):15.2i},n.3q=18(t,e){1a 2n.1f?(15.2z&&15.27(),15.2R(t>15.1D?15.1D:t,e)):15.1p},n.2R=18(t,e,i){1c(o||a.3g(),!2n.1f)1a 15.1E;1c(15.1r){1c(0>t&&!i&&(t+=15.27()),15.1r.2r){15.2z&&15.27();1b r=15.2i,s=15.1r;1c(t>r&&!i&&(t=r),15.1l=(15.1F?15.5g:s.1p)-(15.2F?r-t:t)/15.1C,s.2z||15.3m(!1),s.1r)1d(;s.1r;)s.1r.1p!==(s.1l+s.1E)/s.1C&&s.2R(s.1E,!0),s=s.1r}15.1K&&15.1H(!0,!1),
```

The libraries above depend on `jQuery` being defined globally.
Here is an extract of webpack.config.js

```
const globule = require("globule");
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const extractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const configuration = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        application: [
            "../admin/app.ts"
        ],
        vendor: [
            "bootstrap",
            "bootstrap-select",
            "jquery",
            "jquery-validation",
            "jquery-validation-unobtrusive",
            "angular",
            "moment",
            "ramda"]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "../"),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "vendor",
            filename: "vendor.js"
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            "window.jquery": "jquery",
            Promise: "bluebird",
            Bloodhound: "typeahead"
        }),
        new extractTextPlugin({
            filename: "../../css/[name].css",
            disable: false,
            allChunks: true
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /^((?!\.spec\.ts).)*.ts$/,
                use: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /(node_modules)/
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = configuration;
```

**Edit**

I have also tried the babel loader,

```
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [{ loader: "babel-loader" }]
        },
```

Same error, `require` not defined.

Comment: Are you loading jQuery via a `<script src="">` tag or you have it as a dependency inside `package.json`?

Comment: @tdtd No, its loaded using ProvidePlugin, and made global using that. I am trying to get everything loaded using webpack almost there... but layerslider doesn't seem to be module aware so I have to work around it somehow

Comment: You should probably also use [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader). Checkout the documentation and just add the last example from the README in the github page for `jQuery`. It works fine for me, although I'm not using the `ProvidePlugin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this issue by preparsing your javascript with a loader like babel. https://github.com/babel/babel-loader

Use es 2015 and use the setting modules: false.

See
https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/

If you need a more advanced preset than 2015, this setting also works withthe latest preset, but is configured slightly different

Comment: What changes would I need to make to the configuration file to ensure that only these layer slider dependencies are loaded by the babel loader?

Comment: Babelloader will look at each src file specified and follow the require/import statements to the node_modules folder.. Só it is restricted "as needed" by default (as long as you don't try to use node specific libraries in the browser)

Comment: Thanks: @roberto what do you mean when you say that node modules is not part of the externals definition. I don't follow exactly?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misspoke about this. Externals is an option to mark libraries that you are then responsible for importing separately like via script tag. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: My apologies. You have to configure babel to not build modules. I'll update the answer.